# The log function requires 1 argument(s) at SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to run this script on SQL Server:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[IPAddressToCidr](@IP AS VARCHAR(15))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result INT;
    DECLARE @ipInt BIGINT;

    SET @ipInt = CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(@IP, 1)) + CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(@IP, 2)) * 256 + CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(@IP, 3)) * 65536 + CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(@IP, 4)) * 16777216;
    SET @result = CAST(( 32 - LOG(4294967296 - @ipInt, 2)) AS INT);

    RETURN @result;
END;
```

The result error is:

> Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Procedure IPAddressToCidr, Line 11
>   The log function requires 1 argument(s).

I am trying...

```
SELECT LOG(4294967296,2)  /*this has problem*/
SELECT LOG(4294967296)    /*this one works but with different results */
```

Any help with the `Log()` function with two parameters?

Comment: `log()` with out the 2nd argument returns a value to the base `e`, it is the natural logarithm.

Comment: You need MSSQL 2012: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190319.aspx   `Starting with SQL Server 2012, you can change the base of the logarithm to another value by using the optional base parameter.`

Comment: But LOG(4294967296 - @ipInt, 2) has two parameters

Comment: the 2nd argument isn't supported in sql server 2008 i guess.

Comment: Is there an official resource about the compatibility of this function?

Comment: look at the link @MarcB posted

Comment: "an official source"? **MORE** official than microsoft's own documentation?

Comment: Sorry I missed that !

Comment: So, an alternative would be SELECT LOG(4294967296 /LOG(2) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`SQL Server 2012+`** supports [`LOG(expr, [base])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190319.aspx)

With lower version you can use simple Math to get the result:

```
SELECT LOG(1024)/LOG(2)   -- 10, 2 ^ 10  = 1024
SELECT LOG(1000)/LOG(10)  -- 3, 10 ^ 3   = 1000
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/398877)**</kbd>

**[`Change of base formula`](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/exponential-and-logarithmic-functions/change-of-base-formula-for-logarithms/v/change-of-base-formula):**

```
LOG(@arg,base) = LOG(@arg) / LOG(base)
```

Comment: @vkp Imagine your DB support only natural log, with this formula you can calculate log in any base